# UI not showing for Belvedere Folder Monitor from LifeHacker

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I have just installed [Belvedere](https://github.com/adampash/belvedere) written by people at LifeHacker using AutoHotKey but it won't launch.  I select it in the windows menu but it doesn't appear.

Does anyone know if there is an incompatibility with Windows 7 or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it launches to the task bar, so you need to right click and select manage to get started

[image: Belvedere menu]

Not the most obvious but works now.

Comment: If this worked for you, mark it as the answer.